# Smoothness of contour lines in contourplot

Tags: r, lattice

How can I control the smoothness of the contour lines, when plotting a contour plot using the package lattice in R? The default is particularly unpleasing for low resolution images where the contour edges are sharp.

Edit:
Here is my problem-- the segments join in sharp corners, while I would like a smooth joints.

```
require(lattice)
contourplot(volcano[1:10,1:10])
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example that demonstrates the behavior you describe?

Answer (score 1):

Without a reproducible example, it's a bit tricky to understand exactly what you want.

Anyway, try the `KernSmooth` package. First, we the package and get some data:

```
library("KernSmooth")
data(geyser, package="MASS")
```

next we use the `bkde2D` function to calculate a 2-d kernel density estimate. Change the bandwidth to get more smoothing:

```
x <- cbind(geyser$duration, geyser$waiting)
est <- bkde2D(x, bandwidth=c(0.7, 7))
```

Then do a contour plot on the smoothed output:

```
contour(est$x1, est$x2, est$fhat)
```

Comment: Since we're both guessing that JohnRos just wants aesthetically pleasing contours, a similar method is to turn his image into a `rasterimage` , since IIRC the default conversion does some edge smoothing.

Comment: So the only way is to smooth the image? I would rather smooth only the contours, but leave the image intact.

Comment: How would you propose to smooth?  Contour lines follow data.  That said, here's a hack which _might_ work.  Calculate (but don't plot) contours for a smoothed copy of your image, `smoothlines<-contourplot(volcano)` .  Plot the original image, and then extract the contour line components of `smoothlines` and plot them.  I haven't tried this, nor have I investigated the structure of the `trellis` object `countourplot` returns, but it might work out.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Possibly something along the lines of lend, and ljoin in par(). Alternatively, penalize for non-smooth contours when calculating the contour lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that smooths the example data from the updated question, using `loess` regression.

```
# original data - jagged contours
require(lattice)
contourplot(volcano[1:10, 1:10])

# convert to long form
require(reshape2)
a = melt(volcano)

# use loess to smooth
# higher values of span will deliver more smoothing
b = loess(value ~ Var1+Var2, data=a, span=0.02)

# estimate the smoothed values on our grid
smooth = predict(b, newdata=data.frame(Var1=a$Var1, Var2=a$Var2))
smooth = array(smooth, dim=dim(volcano))

# the result
contourplot(smooth[1:10, 1:10])


# worth also comparing the bigger picture
contourplot(volcano)
contourplot(smooth)
```